# Loop excel worksheets on a TV

Tags: excel, vba

We have a spreadsheet at work that is displayed on a TV screen, it used to only be a single worksheet but sales figures have now been added to other worksheets.

The spreadsheet is set out as so: DisplayData (Worksheet1) - SalesPerson (Worksheet2) - TeamChart (Worksheet3)

The code i've been using is:

```
    Sub changesheet()

intRun = 1

Do While intRun = 1

Worksheets("DisplayData").Select
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

Worksheets("SalesData").Select
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))

Worksheets("GraphData").Select
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))

Loop
```

The code works if i have text on the worksheets, but not if there are any pivot tables are included. I receive the error:

```
Run-time error'9' Subscript out of range
```

[image]

I've uploaded and image also showing how everything is named, just wondered if anyone could help.

Thanks,

Comment: This is now solved, needed to reference the chart rather than the worksheet.

Comment: Glad its solved.  For future reference you can still reference the sheet but you have to use Sheets("GraphData") instead of Worksheet("GraphData") if the chart is on a chart sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your two code examples are different.  Looks like you may trying to access worksheets called "GraphData" and/or "SalesData" which may not exist.

Comment: Cheers, just modified the code to represent how it actually is. I had been messing around with the naming to see if i could get it to work.